# In Google Sheets set dynamic dropdown with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a dynamic dropdown in Google Sheet using Apps Script. I managed to get most parts working except setting the data validation in the cells necessary:

```
function sheetByName(ssId, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  return sheet;
};

function columnByName(sheet, columnName) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var column = data[0].indexOf(columnName);

  return column;
};

function columnValues(sheet, index) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values = [];
  
  for(n=1; n<data.length; ++n) {
    values.push(data[n][index]);
  }

  return values;
}

function columnSetDataValidation(sheet, index, options) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(options)
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .build();

  for(n=1; n<data.length; ++n) {
    var cell = data[n][index];
  };
};

function dropDownBedrijven() {
  var sheetCollegas = sheetByName("<<ID HERE>>", "Collegas");
  var sheetBedrijven = sheetByName("<<ID HERE>>", "Bedrijven");
  
  var getColumnIndexInBedijven = columnByName(sheetBedrijven, "Bedrijf");
  var getColumnIndexInCollegas = columnByName(sheetCollegas, "Bedrijf");

  var bedrijven = columnValues(sheetBedrijven, getColumnIndexInBedijven).filter(item => item);  

  columnSetDataValidation(sheetCollegas, getColumnIndexInCollegas, bedrijven);
  
};
```

I can't manage to get the function `columnSetDataValidation` to set data validation in the required cells.

Do you have any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Is the sheet blank if so the getDataRange() get's nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`range.setDataValidation(rule)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule) with a range.

In your function `columnSetDataValidation` you are correctly building the rule, but are failing to assign the rule to a range. You are looping over the values of the range and then changing the value of `var cell` until the loop ends. Nowhere did you call `range.setDataValidation(rule)`.

Try the following solution:

```js
function columnSetDataValidation(sheet, index, options) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(options)
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .build();

  for(n = 1; n < range.getLastRow(); ++n) {
    var cell = range.getCell(n,index);
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  };
};
```

---

#### References:

- [Range.getCell(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcellrow,-column)
- [Range.setDataValidation(rule)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I made minor adjustments to get the result I was seeking for. But you really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function columnSetDataValidation() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sheet.getRange(2,4,sheet.getLastRow()-1);//putting validation in column 4
  const options=[1,2,3,4,5];
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(options)
    .setAllowInvalid(true)
    .build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I went with the solution Aerials posted because it fit my purpose precisely.